# how to update ShapeGeometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new at three.js, and i tried to update a ShapeGeometry but it didn't work. now i have to remove and readd the shapeMesh evertime.

```
    this.mesh.geometry.dispose()
    this.mesh.material.dispose()
    this.scene.remove(this.mesh)

    //vertex
    this.triangleShape = new THREE.Shape()
    this.triangleShape.moveTo(  -612+this.Eposition.left, 310-this.Eposition.top-25 )
    for(let i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        this.triangleShape.lineTo(data[i][0],data[i][1])
    }
    this.triangleShape.lineTo(  -612+this.Eposition.left+141, 310-this.Eposition.top-25 )
    this.triangleShape.lineTo(  -612+this.Eposition.left+141, 310-this.Eposition.top )
    this.triangleShape.lineTo(  -612+this.Eposition.left, 310-this.Eposition.top )
    this.triangleShape.lineTo(  -612+this.Eposition.left, 310-this.Eposition.top-25 )// close path
    let geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry( this.triangleShape )
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,this.material)
    this.scene.add(this.mesh)
```

Ive tried to write `this.mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true`, but it seems not work

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot update the Shape used by a ShapeGeometry, because the Shape is just a higher-level description of the Geometry that is created from it, not really a part of the Geometry itself.

The point here is this: The Shape is described in terms of vector-graphics, with curves and so on. When you create a ShapeGeometry, three.js will use that description to actually create the geometry-buffers (in this step, curves will be decomposed into lists of line-segments and closed paths will be turned into triangles, see the implementation of [`ShapeGeometry.addShape()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/geometries/ShapeGeometry.js#L58)).

As long as it works performance-wise (shapes not too complex etc), you can of course create a new geometry for every update, but as this process can also be quite expensive you should maybe think about implementing your own Geometry or BufferGeometry to do what you need to do (it's not that complicated. Just have a look at something simple like the Cylinder[Buffer]Geometry for an example).